# Check in return answer from mysql equal the parameter I send

Tags: java, mysql

I built a function in java that searches in the database for 2 values and if they exist return the values;

```
  public List<Conniction> findPath(int one,int two){
    List<Conniction> list = new ArrayList<Conniction>();
    Connection c = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM conniction WHERE oneid="+one+"&& twoid="+two;
    try {
        c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int columncount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        //direct result
        if (columncount > 0) {
            System.out.println("Match one and two found!");
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(processRow(rs));
            }
        }
        else{
            String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM conniction WHERE oneid="+one;
            s = c.createStatement();
            rs = s.executeQuery(sql2);
             metaData = rs.getMetaData();
             columncount = metaData.getColumnCount();
                if (columncount > 0) {
                    System.out.println("One Match found!");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        list.add(processRow(rs));
                    }
                }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;

}
```

How do I check what the values of the parameters that are returned are, to check if its really the right answer for `oneid` and `twoid`. It always returns something different from what I have sent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is the best solution, but you could:
* give the list object with parameters
* and then return a code
* check the code and use the list

your method gets the list as a parameter:

```
    public int findPath(List<Conniction> list, int one, int two) {
        ...
        if (columncount > 0) {
            System.out.println("Match one and two found!");
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(processRow(rs));
            }
            return 2;
        } else {
            String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM conniction WHERE oneid="+one;
            s = c.createStatement();
            rs = s.executeQuery(sql2);
            metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            columncount = metaData.getColumnCount();
                if (columncount > 0) {
                    System.out.println("One Match found!");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        list.add(processRow(rs));
                    }
                    return 1;
                } 
        }
    ...
```

}

in your code, where you call the method you check the return:

```
    ...
    List<Conniction> connlist = new ArrayList<Conniction>();
    int foo = findPath(connlist , one, two);
    if (foo == 1) {
        /*One Match found!*/
        // do something with your connlist-Object;
    } else if (foo == 2) {
        /*Match one and two found!*/
        // do something with your connlist-Object;
    }
```

Comment: hi i cant sent list as parmeter , i can only send one and two  .  i need to check what is the value that return  ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int columncount = metaData.getColumnCount(); mybe there is diffrent function that retrive the colum value ?

Comment: to get the column value of the row in the record set you have to use

Comment: rs.get...();
watch the doku!
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

or the example:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: oops you right i need to look for row!!! sorry
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
int rowCount = rs.last() ? rs.getRow() : 0; // Number of rows in result set. Don't forget to set cyrsor to beforeFirst() row! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two serious problems that prevent it from working:

1. `metaData.getColumnCount()` (unsurprisingly) returns the number of *columns*, not the number of *rows*. The number of columns returned is a constant depending on what is selected in the query. In this case, you `select *`, so `metaData.getColumnCount()` will be exactly the number of columns in the `conniction` table. You don't know how many rows are in the rowset until you process it
2. You probably want *or* logic, not *and*, ie
   `"SELECT * FROM conniction WHERE oneid="+one+" OR twoid="+two`